# Saving photos to cloud

Tags: samsung-mobile

I'm trying a free trial of Google Cloud and have downloaded the "console" but I don't know how to send my photos there to back them up. Place help. Thanks. Judy in Ontario

Comment: Hi Judy, if you are looking to backup personal photos you'll want to create a [Google Drive account](https://www.google.com/drive/). Make sure you to cancel your Google Cloud account so you don't get a surprise charge (although, they do say they won't autocharge).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and answer! I do have a Google Drive account and have saved my photos there but I'm running out of free space. Also, I can't find the place on the Drive to buy Cloud storage. Do you know how?

Comment: Yes! The simplest way to buy more cloud storage is through [Google One](https://one.google.com/about).